# CSS Border Collapse don't work with value collapse

Tags: html, css

I have used the css property `border-collapse: collapse`, but it seems not to be working.

Here is the html

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>This is demo</td>
        <td>This is demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is demo</td>
        <td>This is demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is demo</td>
        <td>This is demo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS

```
table tr td {
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: apply that on table not td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the property on the table, not on the td,

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr td {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```